# Return a ModelAndView Spring MVC PDF Object as a saveable attachment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pdf

I do not have much Spring MVC experience. I inherited some RESTful controller code that finds a record in a database and uses

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView to create a PDF view of the record.
```

Here's the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{uniqueId}.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getProfilePdf(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("uniqueId") String uniqueId {
    Profile profile = getProfileByUniqueId(request, uniqueId);
    Map<String, Object> reportData = buildReportData(profile);
    return new ModelAndView(profileReport, reportData);
}
```

There are lots of supporting objects and methods but since I cannot cut and paste the code in, I'll leave them out for now.

Here's the problem.  When the URL is called the PDF is generated and it pops up in the browser.  If I edit my browser preferences I can get the PDF to pop up in Adobe Acrobat.  But what I NEED is for the popup window that asks you if you want to open or save the file to appear.

I believe the only way to make that happen is to set the Content-disposition to an attachment.

So I added "HttpServletResponse response" to the method parameters and added this to the code:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=profile.pdf");
```

No luck.  I also tried adding a content type:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Still no luck.

I need to learn how to send back a ModelAndView object as a file attachment, or maybe convert it to a byte stream and manually stream it back??  No clue here.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Configuring the `JasperReportsPdfView` to use the correct headers should do the trick.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look.  Brb.

Comment: The view has a property named `headers` by default the `content-disposition` is set to `inline`. You could switch it to `attachment` by providing it hardcoded in the configuration. Drawback is that you don't get to specify the name of the document, as that is static as well.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much!  I simply added a Properties object with one entry:  "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=profile.pdf"  and then added that Properties object to the JasperReportPdfView with setHeaders(Properties) and it pops up the Save/Open window!!!  Thank you so much.  If you make an "Answer" I'll accept it as the right one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [JasperReportsPdfView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsPdfView.html) sets the `Content-Disposition` to `inline` but only if the header isn't preconfigured as something else.

The `JasperReportsPdfView` has a property named `headers` in which you can configure, or override, headers to send along with the generated PDF. If you would include the `Content-Disposition` header in this you can set it to something else, in your case `attachment`.

```
<bean id="yourreport" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView">
    <property name="headers">
        <map>
            <entry key="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; profile.pdf" />
        </map>
    <property>
</bean>
```

Something like this should do the trick (Instead of a `map` you could also use a `props` element).

Comment: Thanks Deinum, this did the trick. I  added a Properties object with one entry: "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=profile.pdf" and then added that Properties object to the JasperReportPdfView object with setHeaders(Properties) and now the call to the web service pops up the Save/Open window.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to stream the PDF file's bytes directly to the output stream and flush the response. In Spring you can do this like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/displayProcessFile/{processInstanceId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> displayProcessFile(@PathVariable String processInstanceId) throws UnauthorizedUserAccessException{
    Document processFile=null;
    try {
        processFile = documentService.retrieveProcessFile(Long.parseLong(processInstanceId));
    } catch (ProcessFileNotFoundExpection e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + processFile.getDocName());
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(processFile.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the question remains, how can I convert the ModelAndView object to an array of bytes?  There doesn't seem to be any method on that object to help me.

Answer (score -7):

Maybe you have to change your browser settings, so that it will ask every time before opening the file directly.

Please find the link: http://malektips.com/google-chrome-prompt-download-file.html#.VnLAgbiGRHw

Also you will have to set:

response.setContentType("application/download");

response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=profile.pdf");

Comment: This is our fall back option, I'd rather not make 3,000 end users change their browser settings. :)